# Will the Origin Store language affect the in-game language? (ME3)

Tags: mass-effect-3, origin

I want to buy Mass Effect 3, and to that purpose, I just created an Origin account. The problem is that I live in Switzerland, and the Origin Store apparently detects my country and then **forces** the German version of the site on me (even though Switzerland has four official languages, but never mind). I can't find any way to change the language: the language menu at the bottom of the site only allows me to choose German (very clever use of a language menu -_-), and if I manually change the URL to the English version (https://www.origin.com/us/store/), it still redirects me to the German URL (https://www.origin.com/de-de/store/). (I already chose English in my account settings, but that didn't change anything.)

Same problem in the PC client, which is obviously just a shell displaying the store website. I can change the language of the client, but it only affects the interface. The content of the store is still shown in German, with the same one-choice language menu.

Despite those powerful incentives to use a cracked version of the game, I'm still willing to fight my way through the interface in a language I barely speak in order to buy the game.

My only concern is that doing so would result in the game being installed in German as well, which is obviously unacceptable. I'm not familiar with Origin *at all*, I've never purchased or installed any game through that platform, so I don't know how games languages are dealt with.

In short: if I purchase and install ME3 through the German version of the Origin Store, will I still be able to play the game in English?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That URL looks like it's directing you to the German store, which is obviously in German.  Is there a storefront specifically for Switzerland?

Comment: @MBraedley not that I know of. Like I said, it does IP detection and redirects me automatically, so I'm assuming it redirects me to the German store because there's no store specifically for Switzerland. But even if there was one, it wouldn't help me since it redirects me without asking me anything. I tried accessing the French store (https://www.origin.com/fr-fr/store/): same result, immediate redirection.

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ However, unlike Switzerland, Singapore has English as an official Language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally tried it anyway and all is good. I purchased the game through the German store (which I translated using Chrome's built-in translation tool). It didn't ask me anything about language, so I don't really know how the game language was determined (is it because my OS (Win8.1) is in English, or because I specified English in my Origin Account settings), but anyway, the game is in English so all is good.